# Typed events on class in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a class in typescript, where I want to emit an event.
Now I know what I want is required for my code to work. But I would like this because it is nice to have.

My class extends [the EventEmitter class](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), and I want to emit the event "check" (this works).
What I want is to have a list of possible events for intellisense, or the like, in Visual Studio Code.

How would I go about doing this in TypeScript?

Comment: You mean [Angular's `EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)? It has a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to specify what can be emitted, you could use a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) for `'check'` and the other valid events.

Comment: I am not using Angular at all, I am talking about the NodeJS EventEmitter

Comment: You should see an option to accept the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways I know of:

**The First One**

Pretty simple, you can use npm packages like [typed-event-emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-event-emitter).

Code example from the package itself:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'typed-event-emitter';

class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
  onValueChanged = this.registerEvent<(newValue: number) => any>();

  private _value: number;

  constructor(value: number) {
    // initialize EventEmitter
    super();

    this._value = value;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    this._value = value;
    this.emit(this.onValueChanged, this._value);
  }
}

let instance = new MyClass(0);
instance.onValueChanged(newValue => {
  console.log(`Value changed: ${newValue}`);
});

instance.value = 27;
```

**The Second One**

In case, you do not want to use npm packages and want to declare on your own, you can use `declare interface` on your classes.

Here is a short example of such declaration:

```
export declare interface Animal {
  on: (event: 'tick', listener: () => void) => this
  emit: (event: 'tick') => boolean
}

export class Animal extends EventEmitter {}
```

Comment: The second option works perfectly for me thanks!